# Displaying only part of an EPS picture

Tags: graphics, eps, bounding-box

I am not sure it is exactly the best place to ask this question but maybe my problem admits a solution with tex.

I have an EPS file but I would like to display only a part of this EPS. Changing the bounding box is not enough as the "hidden" part of the EPS will still get displayed anyway. Is there a way to tell Latex that I just want to display things inside the bounding box ? Or any other solution to my problem ?

(PS: I don't want to convert my EPS to something else in the process as it reduces the quality)

Thanks a lot

Comment: graphicx package `\includegraphics[clip,....` makes it clip to the specified area (which you can specify with clip, trim or viewport keys)

Comment: if you are using the `graphicx` package, there is a `clip` option.  see the manual: `texdoc graphicx`.

Comment: You can see my answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112087/19356).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to crop figures in LaTeX is to use the `trim` argument with `\includegraphics`:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth, clip=true, trim = l b r t]{mywonderfulfigure}
  \caption{My wonderful figure}
  \label{img:wf}
\end{figure}
```

with `l b r t` being how much you want to crop in the left, bottom, right and top direction. The default units are big points (bp). However, any unit available in LaTeX can be used, for example in mm:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth, clip=true, trim = 10mm 20mm 30mm 40mm]{mywonderfulfigure}
  \caption{My wonderful figure}
  \label{img:wf}
\end{figure}
```