# Crop off-page vertices in vector graphic PDF

Tags: graphics, crop, vector, pdfcrop

I have a PDF that contains one page, with a vector image on it.

I want to use the left half of the image on the backside of the front cover-page of my work, and the right half on the front of the back cover-page (since the back of the back cover-page will be on the "outside" of my work).
In other words: If my work were just the front and back cover-pages (nothing in between), you'd see the entire image on the inside of both covers.

I used [`pdfinfo` from xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/) (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2981643/1296709)) to get the dimensions of the original image pdf (163 * 77 pts). Using `pdfcrop` (as per [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70136/31877)) I managed to create both halves, with dimensions 81.5 * 77 pts.

**However**, inspecting the cropped images with [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/), I see that the cropped-out part of the image is still contained in the pdf.

**Is there a way to crop out-of-view vertices of a vector graphic?**
Right now, when they both exist in the same document, the entire image will be included in the final document twice, which makes the file big, and my computer slow when viewing it.

Comment: [Just another smarter solution with PSTricks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112087/19356) or [its copy](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111408/19356) or [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57458/19356) or [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65019/19356).

Comment: Or [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57464/19356) or [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65854/19356).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

save it in a box and then use the optional argument `trim` for `\includegraphics:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parindent=0pt
\newsavebox\mybox
\sbox\mybox{\includegraphics{tiger}}% to get the width
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[trim=0 0 0.5\wd\mybox{} 0,clip]{tiger}% the left

\includegraphics[trim=0.5\wd\mybox{} 0 0 0,clip]{tiger}% the right
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, in the pdf file the image is saved once and showed two times with the *full* width but a different view port.

Comment: This is basically a different flavor of the solution I described in the original question. I was hoping for a solution that does not keep any hidden information (especially if it's stored twice), and tries to clip out-of-view shapes and vertices as best as it can. Maybe my question is not worded clearly enough.

Comment: sorry, I was not clear enough: The image is included once but the cropping is not a real crop it changes only the view port. However, you have included the image once but show the whole image twice with a different view port.